# Run under debug using a real device

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging

I don't understand how to view the debugged app on a real device. To begin with, I see such a picture, it lasts about 3-5 minutes.
[image]
And then I get an error -

> Waiting for a connection from Flutter on M2003J15SC... Error
> connecting to the service protocol: Exception: connection to device
> ended too early

I put dots in the code, and it is important for me to know what is happening there at the time of execution, so I need a debug mode. Help please, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you connecting to the device? Cable? Wifi?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson cable